# Conditional method chaining in apex

Tags: design-patterns, salesforce, apex, method-chaining

I have a class **LogException**

```
public class LogException extends Exception {
public String ModuleName {get; set;}
public String StackTrace {get; set;}
public String ClassName {get; set;}
public String MethodName {get; set;}
public String ExceptionCause {get; set;}

public void log(Exception ex)
{
    try
    {
        extractExceptionData(ex); 
        writeToObject(ex); 

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
         new LogException().Module('LogException').log(e);            
    }

}

public LogException Module(String Name)
{
    ModuleName = name;
    return this;
}

public LogException ExceptionCause(String cause)
{
    ExceptionCause = cause;
    return this;
}

public void extractExceptionData(Exception ex)
{
    try
    {
        stackTrace = ex.getStackTraceString().substringBefore('\n');
        className = stackTrace.substringAfter('.').substringBefore('.');    
        methodName = stackTrace.substringBefore(':').substringAfter(className).substringAfter('.');    
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        new LogException().Module('LogException').log(e); 
    }

}

public void writeToObject(Exception ex)
{
    try
    {
        // insert to object(database) here   
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        new LogException().Module('LogException').log(e);     
    }

}
```

}

I implemented method chaining here. Therefore, I can call methods like

```
new LogException().Module('unitTestModule').Log(ex);

new LogException().ExceptionCause('divided by zero').Log(ex);

new LogException().Module('unitTestModule').ExceptionCause('Probably no data in account').Log(ex);

new LogException().ExceptionCause('Probably no data in account').Module('unitTestModule').Log(ex);
```

My question is, how can I implement the class so that, I can only call `ExceptionCause` right after `Module`?

Comment: Why not just use an overloaded constructor? The method chaining doesn't appear to add anything, and is much more verbose than a well-chosen set of constructors.

Comment: @DavidReed : Can you enlighten me / give me a idea how can I implement overloaded constructor to implement it ?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use method chaining here. I'd just override the constructor to populate the parameters needed:

```
public LogException(String module, String exceptionCause) {
}

public LogException(String module) {
    this(module, null);
}
// etc.
```

The only thing you're not going to be able to do here is have two constructors that both take a single `String` parameter - you have to be willing to define a hierarchy of required through additional optional parameters, like `exceptionCause` here.

The reference documentation is [Apex Constructors](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_constructors.htm).